# Put a Fitting Curve on Top in R

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
ggplot(f, aes(x=rev)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, position= position_dodge(0.5), 
               color="black", fill="cadetblue4") + 
  ggtitle("Histogram of Maximum Revenue")+labs( x="Revenue", y="Number of Observations")
```

I try adding `+ geom_density()` but it displays the same plot as without the geom_density(). It does nothing. It doesn't throw an error message..

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". An error message? Output but not as expected?

Comment: It displays the same plot as without the geom_density(). It does nothing. It doesn't throw an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the density plot is difficult to see as the scales are different. Try this:

```
ggplot(f, aes(x=rev)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),
                 binwidth = 0.5, position= position_dodge(0.5), 
                 color="black", fill="cadetblue4") + 
  ggtitle("Histogram of Maximum Revenue")+labs( x="Revenue", y="Number of Observations") +
  geom_density()
```

If you want the y-axis to be on the count scale: see the last code example in [this discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280588.html).

Comment: That shows the curve but now the y-axis is density, not count. I would like the y-axis to be count/Number of Observations, not density.

Comment: That is slightly trickier, you need to use the `binwidth` value in `geom_density`. I'll edit the answer with a link.